# Can xparse distinguish arguments inside braces and single-token arguments without braces?

Tags: macros, foreach, xparse, arguments

The `\foreach` command from `pgffor` package has a good feature that it can distinguish arguments inside braces and single-token arguments without braces:

```
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {do some thing}

\def\myvar{1,2,3}
\foreach \i in \myvar {do other thing}
```

Can I use `xparse` (without manually define auxiliary macros) to define this kind of commands:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \MyCommand {???} {
  If (#1 is inside braces) Then
    Do Some Thing
  Else
    Do Other Thing
  End
}
```

so that the command accepts both types of arguments and do different things accordingly?

```
\MyCommand {1,2,3} % do some thing
\MyCommand \myvar  % do other thing
```

Comment: Well, another alternative would be the peek_analysis function family. (although, you know, it's not possible in the general case and there's a corner case where peek_analysis fails)

Comment: No unless you use the dreaded `G`-type argument (please don't :).  For `m`-type arguments, `xparse` (`ltcmd` nowadays) uses simple TeX argument grabbing, as that covers nearly all use cases.  As user202279 said, you can use `\peek_meaning(_ignore_spaces):NTF \c_group_begin_token ...` to emulate that yourself

Comment: Replace the first paragraph with ”The `\foreach` command has a nasty feature…”

Comment: @egreg Then how would you do if you are designing the syntax of `\foreach` command?

Comment: `\foreach*{<var spec>}[<options>]{<list>}{<code>}` where the `*` announces use of a command for the list.

Comment: @L.J.R. And, in addition to the above, I'd define it so *not* to have the `<var spec>` in the arguments: a `#1` for the varying index can be implied; more complex parsing such as `#1/#2` could be set in the `<options>`, say something like `vars=#1/#2`. And I surely wouldn't allow that a nested `\foreach` can be inserted without properly bracing it. Slight complication: nested loops must use `##1` for the variable index, but once it is documented, it becomes easy to follow.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Why `\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:N` is deprecated and removed from `interfaces3`?

Comment: @L.J.R. Because providing `ignore_spaces` versions doubled the (six) basic `peek` functions, and could be replaced completely by `\peek_remove_spaces:n`.  You can use `\peek_remove_spaces:n { \peek_meaning:N ... }` instead

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At the document command level, Lamport's book has always been clear: there are *no* arguments which are 'always N-type'. Handling the difference in semantics between `{X}` and `X` would be down to a programming-layer interface or a custom parser (*e.g.* TikZ doesn't use standard LaTeX syntax, so couldn't be implemented using `ltcmd`).

Answer (score 1):

The `tokcycle` package can tell whether things are being absorbed in braced groups or not, and can do "some thing" or "other thing" based on that status.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{%
  ``Do other thing'' with ``#1''\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\Groupdirective{%
  ``Do some thing'' with ``#1''\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\Macrodirective{%
  ``Do other thing'' with ``\string#1''\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\stripgroupingtrue
\let\mycommand\tokencyclexpress
\begin{document}
\mycommand{ab cd}.

\mycommand A.

\mycommand\macroname.
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  Generally, unbraced spaces won't be an issue following the invocation of `\mycommand`, since they will not be part of the argument.  However, if one was concerned about the argument being an unbraced implicit space, a `\Spacedirective` can be defined to handle that, too.

p.p.s. This implementation is doing "some" or "other" things while the token stream is still being absorbed.  If one requires the some/other thing to only occur at the conclusion of the argument absorption, that is a trivial change...as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{%
  \addcytoks{``Do other thing'' with ``#1''}%
  \tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\Groupdirective{%
  \addcytoks{``Do some thing'' with ``#1''}%
  \tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\Macrodirective{%
  \addcytoks{``Do other thing'' with ``\string#1''}%
  \tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw}%
}
\stripgroupingtrue
\let\mycommand\tokencyclexpress
\begin{document}
\mycommand{ab cd}.

\mycommand A.

\mycommand\macroname.
\end{document}
```